# Setting up Wordpress MU off of a subdomain

Tags: multisite

I would like to create a network using Wordpress MU, but I want to keep certain sites together by theme.

For example, if I was setting up an ecommerce site, it would look like shop.domain.com/site-name

Likewise, setting up a restaurant site would be restaurant.domain.com/site-name

But these would really be on different networks. I want to do this to be able to feature those sites by category on a network homepage.

Is this possible? Would it be efficient, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that is possible zutto.  WP multi-site requires you to select either subdomain or subfolders for organizing your network.  It is a one or the other, not both I'm afraid.